# Random 2D array without 3 same in a row or column

Tags: c#

Hello looking for solution to fill 2D array with random values from 1-8 without 3 same numbers next to each other in a column or in a row.

```
Random random = new Random();

for (var row = 0; row < RowCount; row++)
{
    for (var column = 0; column < RowCount; column++)
    {
        tiles[row, column] = random.Next(1, 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: So an array of arbitrary size, but you can't have the, for example: `3,3,3` appear in the same row (and same for columns too)?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is simple: fill your matrix from right to left and from top to down. To avoid duplicates at any cell look two cells up and two cells left, and if they have same value, call `random.Next(..)`  again. Next code will create that matrix:

```
// this method checks cells that up to current
private static bool EqualsUp(int i, int j, int[,] matrix, int value) => i >= 0 && matrix[i, j] == value;

// this method checks cells that left to current
private static bool EqualsLeft(int i, int j, int[,] matrix, int value) => j >= 0 && matrix[i, j] == value;

public static int[,] GenerateMatrix(int h, int w)
{
    var matrix = new int[h, w];
    var random = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    for (var j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        while (true)
        {
            var cellValue = random.Next(1, 9); // note: second value is exclusive, so to generate values from 1 to 8 pass 9 as second argument
            if (EqualsUp(i - 1, j, matrix, cellValue) && EqualsUp(i - 2, j, matrix, cellValue))
                continue; // need to regenerate cellValue
            if (EqualsLeft(i, j - 1, matrix, cellValue) && EqualsLeft(i, j - 2, matrix, cellValue))
                continue; // need to regenerate cellValue

            matrix[i, j] = cellValue;
            break;
        }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can't guarantee that the function will exit. You could (in theory at least, if not in practice) repeatedly generate the _same_ random number. A better approach would be on the next attempt (or even the current attempt) if the two above or the two to the left are the same, generate a random number with a range one less than usual. If the new number is disallowed value, substitute the maximum value. Of course, you also need to check both up and left, because they might both have two repeated values and they might exclude two different values.